# How to register custom Object type in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, webrtc

I use [Temasys](https://temasys.atlassian.net/wiki/display/TWPP/WebRTC+Plugins) plugin to support Video calls in Safari. What it does is, it converts the **video** element to an **object** with

> type = "application/x-temwebrtcplugin"

Eg:-

```
<object id="video_remote" type="application/x-temwebrtcplugin" width="500" height="282" style="display: inline;">
  <param name="pluginId" value="video_remote">
  <param name="pageId" value="f**">
  <param name="windowless" value="true">
  <param name="streamId" value="4">
  <param name="AllowScriptAccess" value="always">
</object>
```

Now, when I try to access this Object with `jQuery("#video_remote")`, I get:

[image: Screenshot]

On this element no jQuery method works, like (`jQuery("#video_remote").attr("id") gives undefined`)

But, when I remove the **type="application/x-temwebrtcplugin"**, jQuery returns the Object element properly.

So, How can I register a custom type with jQuery, so that it finds Object element of any type?